# Verb Question (Become vs Became)

Tags: grammar

I'm not sure which one of these is the correct one:

Many natives have found their courage deep within, cultivated it, and ***become*** aware of what was going on in their country.

Many natives have found their courage deep within, cultivated it, and ***became*** aware of what was going on in their country.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there more context to this? The sentence right before this one might help clear this up.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely "become."

The easiest way to think of this is to look at the way the sentence is structured. This sentence:

> Many natives have found their courage deep within, cultivated it, and become aware of what was going on in their country.

is a subject, verb, object sentence where the object is a list of 3 things:

- finding courage deep within
- cultivating it
- becoming aware of what was going on in their country

This can be split into 3 separate sentences:

- Many natives have found their courage deep within.
- They have cultivated it.
- They have *become* aware of what was going on in their country.

Since the same grammatical tense is being used everywhere in the list, the past perfect "they have *become*" is correct (as opposed to "they have *became*," which even sounds wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for answering. Well, what can I say, it seems that people are slightly divided on this one, just like I was. Either it's "become" or both can be used...

Does anyone here have a final answer? In any case, since become seems to be correct under all circumstances, I will go with it.

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is "become".

The reason is because all of the verbs are in a parallel structure with "have", so all of them should be in their past participle form. (e.g. "go - went - **gone**").

For "find" or "cultivate", the past participle is the same as the simple past form. That is:

> go - went - gone
>
> find - found - found
>
> cultivate - cultivated - cultivated

While "become" is a little strange. It's past participle is the same as its *plural present* form. That is:

> become - became - become

So while I "have cultivated" something, I "have become" something.

Answer (score -1):

Both are correct, grammatical and make sense. They mean the same thing, except that the tense of *become* depends on whether *have* applies to both the clauses or only the first clause.

> {Many natives **have** {found their courage deep within, cultivated it, and **become** aware of ….}}

vs.

> {Many natives {**have** found their courage deep within, cultivated it,} and **became** aware of ….}}

In the first case, it may imply a simple list, while in the second case, a cause-effect relationship may be implied -- finding their courage and cultivating it may have been the cause of their becoming aware.

It depends on the context and the author's intent.

Comment: "Have found" is a present perfect form, and so is focused on the present result. It is unnatural to combine a present perfect and a simple past form in parallel. "I have seen the Eiffel tower and went to Germany." is rather unclear in tense, and is unnatural.  Further, if we had a cluster of two parallel verbs, those parallel verbs should be connected with a conjunction. That is, it should be "Many natives have found their courage deep within **and** cultivated it, and *are becoming* aware of...  (I changed the last verb form to match the present tense of the sentence as a whole.)

Comment: @Drazex Please read the answer again.

Comment: I did read it. It is not correct. Where we are comparing causes, the perfect aspect is *especially* relevant, as the perfect usually relates to effects from causes (as well as other uses that aren't as relevant here). The tense of the whole sentence should agree, be it past or present, and the "present perfect" is a *present* form, as its name implies, despite expressing past events.  If the sentence were "Many natives found their courage deep within, cultivated it, and became aware of..." that would be one thing, as it would be in the past tense, but this is not the case.

Answer (score -2):

If these two are your only options, worded exactly, definitely go with "*became*" - because its tense agrees with the rest of the sentence. "*Become*" by itself, as a standalone word, indicates present tense. You can also see it as a progression: the natives *have found* (somewhere in the past, as a "single event") their courage, *then* they *cultivated* it, and, *because of that*, they *became aware* (of what *was* going on). The last bit is important, because whatever *was* going on was happening when the natives *became* aware of it.

Comment: This is *not* correct. The "have" applies to the whole set, not just the first term, because of the parallel construction. What is more, the tense of the whole subject is the *present* tense (using the present perfect aspect "have done"), which means that the past participle of "become" which is, itself, "become" must be used.

Comment: The tense could be present in a specific context, but most likely isn't. Might need the previous sentence for this.

Comment: This sentence is in the present perfective aspect. That is a *present* form. The present perfect is used when something that occurred in the past now affects the present situation. By using the simple past, you are placing the result before the cause. "I have been to Japan so I know some Japanese." is correct. "I have been to Japan so I knew some Japanese." is not correct, because effect (knowing some Japanese) precedes the cause (going to Japan). In this case, the natives "have found" their courage (*now*), and so *have done*, *are doing*, or *will do* something further.

Comment: I tried doing my research here, and there seems to be plenty of usage of present perfect + past simple in the same sentence. In fact, I found multiple questions here or on ELL relating to just that, to the point that the question might be a duplicate. Either way, the answers I found suggest that such usage is accepted, but they call it idiomatic, and it does depend on context.

Comment: Doing some research myself, most of the hits I get have the present perfect coming *after* the simple past. One example I found here was "First, the European Union entered a crisis that it could not solve and that has increased in intensity." This would be logical, as the effect is in the present, while the cause is in the past. "There was a crisis and it is bigger now." *This* question, however, is the opposite. Placing a past tense after the present perfect is jumping backwards in time.

Comment: This answer in particular is quite clear and demonstrates the logical order of tenses I'm talking about: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6239/present-perfect-with-simple-past

Comment: The answer conveniently links http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/sequence.htm, which states: "Present Perfect or Past Perfect...For any purpose, use the past tense". It gives two examples, one being "She *has grown* a foot since she *turned* nine". This would normally rule out "become" as a valid option, but the whole rule seems to specify "dependent clause" - now this is where I am rusty, but I believe there is no dependent clause because it uses "and" in the sentence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81807/discussion-between-drazex-and-htmlcoderexe).